# Can vs. Could in the reply "It can/could be in the car"

Tags: modal-verbs

I’ve made another mistake in a modals test, in the can/could segment. 
The following exchange was presented:

> Where’s my bag? Have you seen it? – No, but it *_* be in the car.

I decided that both ‘can’ and ‘could’ are appropriate in the underscored position. 
The key contained only ‘could’.
I’m curious why ‘can’ here is wrong:

> Where’s my bag? Have you seen it? – No, but it **can* be in the car.

In the Russian language, we use only the present-tense form of ‘can’ in such hypothetical answers: the past of 'can' would sound literal and ridiculous; so one may tend to carbon-copy the 'can' construction into English, failing to notice the difference in sense.

I’ve consulted a textbook and it says that ‘can’ tends to be used to convey a more general meaning. An example is given:

> The weather *can* change very quickly in the mountains. (in general)
>
> The weather is nice now, but it *could* change. (the weather now, not
>   in general).

Is it in the same vein with the car in the example? Does “It can be in the car” sound too general while “It could be in the car” zeroes in on the immediate situation?

Would the sentence with ‘can’ come out too haughty in the context, that is, a person turns for advice concerning situation at hand, and gets a generic sentence, almost telling him “well, your bag, speaking generally, can fit in the car, go guess the rest of it”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modal verbs can be a little tricky. When you suggest a possibility for a specific situation at hand, such as "Where is my bag (right now)?" you are hinting at where you think it "might" be. Since you are only talking about the bag in this specific instance you should use "could" or "might" to indicate you are responding to this situation.
As you also correctly discovered, "can" is reserved for "general truths" (a kind of [zero conditional](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/type0/menu.php): "If you smoke too much it can kill you").

The examples your textbook gave you are good. Try to contrast "right now/this specific situation" = "could" vs. "in general" = "can", as a rule of thumb.

To answer the last part of your question, "can" just doesn't really fit in this situation. Since you were asked about a specific situation "Where's my bag?" you really can't use "can". You can be plenty haughty by choosing your phrasing rather than your modal:

> No, but it **could** be in the car along with your head that you clearly left there!

Lastly, and just a piece of advice, from the way I view "can" and "could" as **possibility modals**: Don't think of them as present and past (like when they describe ability/permission), but rather: general = can, specific = could.

Comment: It is possible to use *can* where you wrote *you really can't* use it, though we would normally hear it in limited contexts and to convey special meanings. Consider: Q: *Where's my bag?* A: *Good question. Where can it be? Let's see. It can be on the table. It can be in the car . . . .* Or, Q: *Where's my bag? It can't be in the car.* A: *It* can *be in the car. [In fact, I just saw it in the car.].*

Answer (score 3):

*Can* is not often used to express *possibility*. I think in British English it is rare or non-existent to do so, and in American English we don't usually use *can* with this meaning. Instead, *could* is used, or *may*/*might*.

So to express

> It is possible that the bag is in the car.

use

> It may be in the car.
>   It might be in the car.
>   It could be in the car.

*Can* is barely, if at all, workable for me (AmE) with this meaning. The last two, *might* and *could*, express a lesser degree of possibility that the bag is in the car.

To express the opposite

> It is not possible that the bag is in the car.

We do use *can't*/*cannot*.

> It can't be in the car. I took it out of the car and put it somewhere else.

We don't use *may not*, *might not* to express this negation.

There is another negation, the one that states

> It is possible that the bag is not in the car. I am not sure if it is there or not.

Here, we use *It may/might not be in the car* but **not** *can't/cannot* or *couldn't/could not* for this. I know few people who would say *It mightn't be in the car* and no one who would say *It mayn't be in the car*.

---

The sentence

> The weather is nice now, but it could change.

is about possiiblity. This is the same as the sentence about the bag.

Again, to express

> It is possible that the weather change

the use of *could* is much more idiomatic. As is *may*/*might*.

The other sentence

> The weather can change very quickly in the mountains.

is not about possibilty, but ability. Note that we can be sure about this by substituting *could*. I've said above that *could* is idiomatic for possibility; but *could* here

> &&The weather could change very quickly in the mountains.

is not at all felicitous to express possibility. This is in contrast to the felicitous use of *could* in the sentences above to express possibility. (Note that the sentence is grammatical to express past ability.)

Instead, *can* is being used in its "dynamic" sense of expressing *ability.* Note, of course, that 'the weather' does not have a will of its own. But we often ascribe ability to inanimate objects. Compare:

> This Porsche can accelerate from 0 to 60 in 3.1 seconds.

This is talking about ability. This is different from expressing possibility. And a Porsche salesperson knows that quite well! Using *could* here would represent either *past ability* (This Porsche could accelerate from 0 to 60 in 3.1 seconds when I first bought it) or irrealis (This Porsche could accelerate from 0 to 60 in 3.1 seconds if you fitted it with a more powerful engine).

*Can* in the sense of ability very often is replaceable by *is able to*.